# php script to fix text in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have several products in magento with an incorrect product description.

Example: `"This&nbsp;text&nbsp;has&nbsp;some&nbsp;mistakes."`

As you can see, the text uses `&nbsp;` as a placeholder. I want to replace each `&nbsp;` with a real placeholder.

I want to write a php script that will load the description from the database, fix the text and then save it.

Do you know how I could do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_replace` .

Create a file `Updatedesc.php` inside your magento root folder and write the below code in that file and then execute it with below URL http://www.yourdomain.com/Updatedesc.php

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); 
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
               ->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach($_productCollection as $_product)
{   
     try
     {
          $description = $_product->getDescription();
          $newDescription = str_replace(" ","|", $description);
          $_productCollection->setDescription($newDescription);
          $_productCollection->save();
     }
     catch(Exception $e){
          echo $e->getMessage();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help! I don't understand what this does: `$_productCollection->setStoreId(2);`
I want to change the description of every product, so I need to add a foreach.
I came up with this:

```
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){
    $description = $_product->getDescription();
    $newDescription = str_replace(" ","|", $description);
    $_productCollection->setDescription($newDescription);
    $_productCollection->save();
}
```

Comment: $_productCollection->setStoreId(2) is used to specify the new description for the product in store no 2. You need to specify the store_id just incase you want to edit the description for a apecific store only.

Comment: and yes its the correct way to update description for all the products.

Comment: ok thank you, i created a php file in my root directory with your code, how do i run the script?